# Safe support for erc-1155

Tags: gnosis-safe

Hi I’m simply trying to send erc1155 tokens from my safe and I’ve tried asking support and reading every doc available and I’m told repeatedly to use a fallback handler. But there are no docs or specific instructions how to use a fallback handler to support erc1155.

Can anyone supply a set by step walk through?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send your ERC-1155 tokens to safe . You can simply do this by using metamask open your metamask go to nft's and transfer to the safe address. If you want to send your NFT's from Safe to another wallet . Go to safe dashboard and enter your address where you want to send your NFT.